# Allocating an object of abstract class type in OMNET ++ define_module

Tags: c++, omnet++, wireless

I build OMNET project. The main codes as follow:
Routing.h

```
class  INET_API Routing : public cSimpleModule, public ILifecycle, public cListener {  }
```

Routing.ned

```
simple Routing like IManetRouting{  }
```

Routing.cc

```
Define_Module(Routing);
```

When I build the project, the error- Allocating an object of abstract class type Routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this is correct. You cannot create an instance of an abstract class. You MUST implement all the methods defined by `ILifecycle` and `cListener` otherwise the behavior of the class is undefined and it is considered abstract.

Comment: I will implement all, thank you.